# My thermostat will not start my air conditioner

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning

I remember the same thing last summer where occasionally it would take a number of hours for the ac to kick on after I switched to cool and the temperature was above the threshold.  The funny thing is that I have no problem in the past winter with heat.  The heater came on as expected right away.

Switch to this summer, my thermostat is above the threshold, my batteries fresh and my switch on cool and auto.  Neither auto nor fan will trigger any action from my air conditioner.  Even after waiting hours and days, no activity.  I tried to go to my fuse box and reset the power which is clearly labeled to my ac until, but nothing improved.

How can I get my ac running again?  I really don't want to mess with replacing the thermostat (which is a modern programmable one) and the wiring that goes with that.

Comment: sounds like a bad thermostat

Comment: Do you know what the dead band is? From heat to cool there is usually a 3-7 degree dead band meaning if you set your system to heat it will keep it at that temp but switch to cool and it might need to be 3-7 degrees warmer befor the cooling kicks in, try turning the temp set pound down and see if that solves your no cooling problem.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Why was this post deleted?  I gave an answer to my question.  I turned on the heat and then turned it back to air conditioner and the air conditioner started working and now works.